# iOS Mobile Scrolling Best Practice

Tags: android, ios, scrolling, ux-designer

My designer came up with this design which I like but the top part, what is a best practice to scroll here.  Should the table cells go behind the searchbox, should we have a divider of some sort? What are designers doing these days?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS, most often the search is hidden and launched only after the swap down. As an example, you can open the settings on your iPhone and see where the search is located.
Feel free to try this feature, it's fairly native behavior and it's the easiest to implement.

Comment: I like that, and didnt know.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy [what Apple does](https://osxdaily.com/2015/09/22/search-settings-ios/). It'll follow [Jakob's Law](https://www.nngroup.com/videos/jakobs-law-internet-ux/) and also stays away from the [false consensus effect](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/false-consensus/) (ie avoid "this design which I like...).